# Can we put the "Raspberry Pi as power switch" on hold?

Tags: discussion

The "raspberry pi as power switch" question is not particularly good, and is very old, but continue to attract dubious quality answers. While it would be sad to close it altogether, maybe it is time to put it on hold?

[Use Raspberry Pi to control PC's power switch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/raspberry-pi-as-power-switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold is designed for questions that have problems (aka off topic or to broad etc.). Rather dubious answers should be downvoted - or in worst case scenario flagged for moderator attention. I also don't feel that the answers in question warrant protecting the question (i.e. they are not just me too answers etc.) at this point.